# Array multidimensional python

Tags: python, django

Tenho uma série de dados que gostaria de organizar por titulo, exemplo;

```
movies = [
   'movie': [
      'legenda' [
         'dub', 'leg', 'nac'
       ],
      'time': [
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5
      ]
   ]
   ....
]
```

Tentei com `dict()` com `list()` e ainda não consegui nenhum resultado.

```
 for movie in soup.find_all(class_="filme"):
    movies.update({'title', movie.h4.a.get_text()})
    for legend in movie.select(".movie-info .leg img"):
        movies.update({'leg', legend.get('alt')})
```

Desta maneira ele só vai atualizar o que eu tenho, não sei como criar esse multidimensional com python (ainda)

Answer (score 1):

Estás a tentar definir um dict como se fosse uma lista. Experimenta antes definir o dict com os parêntesis `{ }`, desta forma:

```
movies = {
   'movie': {
      'legenda': ['dub', 'leg', 'nac'],
      'time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   }
   ....
}
```

Um dict, ao contrário de uma lista, é sempre um grupo de combinações entre uma chave (ex: `legenda`) e um valor (ex: `['dub', 'leg', 'nac']`)